# Get text from EditText into string to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext, gettext

I've been searching and I don't find the way. The solutions I found doesn't work or I don't know how to implement them.

My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText txtDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameE);
        final String nameE2 = txtDescription.getText().toString();

        Button bVerify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verifyB);
        bVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /** Called when the user clicks the Next button */
                Log.d("EditText", nameE2);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, nameE2);
                startResultActivity(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public void startResultActivity(View view){
        Intent sra = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(sra);

    }
    }
```

This, already in my code, are the 2 solutions I found everywere, but I don't know how to use them:

```
 EditText txtDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameE);
    String nameE2 = txtDescription.getText().toString();
```

&

```
Log.d("EditText", nameE2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, nameE2);
```

Inside activity_main, among other things, I've this EditText and this button:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/nameE"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NameTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/verifyB"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/verifyB"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameE"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

In the "ractivity" layout I've this PlainText. In this one I want to add the EditText input from the other activity/layout.

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello  + nameE2 + . Are you sure you want to accept these terms?"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />
```

"nameE2" must be the string of the EditText.

I would love to know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance. If you need additional data, tell me.

Comment: startResultActivity(null);    null ???

Comment: Why you have made this method  startResultActivity(null); ??!!

Comment: @AkashDubey

Because if I put:
startResultActivity(intent);

It marks it in red and putting the mouse over the box says:
startResultActivity (android.view.View) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (android.content.Intent)

Comment: I solved that problem
Thanks, that was part of the error
I think the string passes to the ResultActivity, but I don't know how to put that String in a plainText at the layout. `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello + nameE2 + . Are you sure you want to accept these terms?" android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />` It Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine, with a little modification.

```
bVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /** Called when the user clicks the Next button */
        Log.d("EditText", nameE2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, nameE2);
        startResultActivity(null);
    }
});
```

Here instead of pass `null` to `startResultActivity()`, pass the created Intent similar to this:

```
bVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String nameE2 = txtDescription.getText().toString();
        /** Called when the user clicks the Next button */
        Log.d("EditText", nameE2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, nameE2);
        startResultActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And the `startResultActivity()` method have to look like this:

```
public void startResultActivity(Intent intent){

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

EDIT:
As I mentioned, you cannot use your variable directly in your layout file.

You have to set it dynamically. You can do that in your ResultActivity's `onCreate()` method. It have to look similar to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ractivity); // your second layout file

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    String stringResult = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String textViewText = "Hello "+ stringResult +". Are you sure you want to accept these terms?";
    textView.setText(textViewText);

}
```

This will work if in your second layout file there is a `Textview` with *textView* id.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I had to change to intent, and also I had to change the startResultActivity method.

Now I think the string passes to the ResultActivity, but I don't know how to put that String in a plainText at the layout.

`<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello  + nameE2 + . Are you sure you want to accept these terms?"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />`

It Doesn't work

Comment: From your layout file you can't refer to variable from your Activity. If you want to show in the new Activity the passed string you have to set it dynamically. In your `ResultActivity` add the following code the the `onCreate()` method: `TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String stringResult = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        
        textView.setText(stringResult);`

Comment: That works, I had to put 
`TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);`
Because without `(TextView)` I got a warning.

Now I just need to know how to put the string on the layout, because it won't let me refer to the `stringResult`. Sorry for knowing so little. And thanks, you have helped me a lot.
`<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello + stringResult + . Are you sure you want to accept these terms?"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
/> `

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. Now I understand the code. ^^ See you around!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
 startResultActivity(null);
```

in your `Button onClick`

Comment: Because if I put: startResultActivity(intent); It marks it in red and putting the mouse over the box says: startResultActivity (android.view.View) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (android.content.Intent)

Comment: no need to put `startResultActivity(intent)` . just put startActivity(intent);

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the error
I think the string passes to the ResultActivity, but I don't know how to put that String in a plainText at the layout. `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello + nameE2 + . Are you sure you want to accept these terms?" android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />` It Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                EditText txtDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameE);
                final String nameE2 = txtDescription.getText().toString();

                Button bVerify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verifyB);
                bVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        /** Called when the user clicks the Next button */
                        Log.d("EditText", nameE2);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, nameE2);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

changed onClickListener to

```
bVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /** Called when the user clicks the Next button */
            final String nameE2 = txtDescription.getText().toString();
            Log.d("EditText", nameE2);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, nameE2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

you are getting text at start when it does not have any text so move

```
final String nameE2 = txtDescription.getText().toString();
```

inside onClick of bVerify view so it will read current text when client will click on button

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the error
I think the string passes to the ResultActivity, but I don't know how to put that String in a plainText at the layout. `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello + nameE2 + . Are you sure you want to accept these terms?" android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />` It Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change `startResultActivity(null);` into `startActivity(intent);`.
And then in the other Activity where you need to use that String:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String getExtra = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
TextView.setText(getExtra);
```

Comment: I did it.
`public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ractivity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String getExtra = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
        TextView.setText(getExtra);
    }
}`

setText gets a warning: 
"cannot be refereced from static content"
How can I solve that?

Thanks, that has been helpful

Comment: The id of the TextView in your "ractivity" is textView, correct? Try changing `TextView.setText(getExtra)` to `textView.setText(getExtra)` . In case you didn't even cast it, do the following: `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Comment: I already upvoted, just wait until I get 15 reputation. Thanks :)